# how to pass in parameter of hibernate config

Tags: java, hibernate

i am trying to make multiple hibernate.cfg.xml files as each will have different connection properties in them.  how do i specify which cfg file i want inside of each class that uses them?

here is my session factory:

```
public class DatabaseUtilities {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory(String configFile) {
        try {
            return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure(configFile).buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        // Close caches and connection pools
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }
}
```

of course this throws errors right now because i dont know how to pass the parameter into the object at the top.

this is how i call the session factory from my class

```
Session s = DatabaseUtilities.getSessionFactory().openSession();
```

how can i modify this code to take the string of the .xml passed in by the class using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're encapsulating the access to the SessionFactory in a Singleton-way, you could perhaps rewrite it not to follow the [`Static block initialization` but `Lazy initialization`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Lazy_initialization):

```java
public class DatabaseUtilities {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory(String configFile) {
        try {
            return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure(configFile).buildSessionFactory();           
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }   

    public static synchronized SessionFactory getSessionFactory(String configFile) {
            if (sessionFactory == null) {
                sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory(configFile);   
            }
            return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        // Close caches and connection pools
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }

    private DatabaseUtilities() {}
}
```

Now you can call your utilities class this way:

```java
DatabaseUtilities.getSessionFactory("path/to/hibernate.cfg.xml");
```